# endless while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
int option=0;

while (option1!=1 || option1!=2){                   
    System.out.println("Give 1 for the first list which includes what we have in our exhibition");
    System.out.print("and 2 which we have not:"); // 2 print because i want to show at two different lines
    option1= Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());} // when i give 1 or 2 as an option it doesn't goes out frome the loop
```

Comment: i want to repeat until user gives the number 1 or 2

Comment: `option != 1 || option != 2` is always true, you need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an infinite loop:

```
while(option1!=1 || option1!=2)
```

Since `option1` can never *simultaneously* equal *both* `1` *and* `2`, then this condition will always evaluate to `true` and the loop will always continue.  You probably meant to use the logical "and" operator (`&&`) in your comparison:

```
while(option1!=1 && option1!=2)
```

That way the loop will end if `option1` ever equals one of those two options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say `option1!=1 && option1!=2`, not `option1!=1 || option1!=2`

Please remember to format your code so it's readable. Just add four spaces in front of each line.